# Internal / External Link Issue with jQuery Mobile

Tags: php, jquery, mobile

I have a few mobile web pages. Several of them are internally linked from the same file (index.php) and work fine. Eg: #first to #second and #second to #third. The problem comes when I get to #third and submit a form query to an external file process.php (which is located in a same directory). I can get to the process.php file fine but I need to insert a hyperlink on this page to link back to the original page (#first inside index.php). I have tried several suggestions but no matter what I do the browser seems to append index.php to the URL so is actually bringing me back to #third rather than #first.

EG: http://localhost/website/third.php#index.php

I have tried:

```
<a href="index.php">Clicky</a>
<a href="#first">Clicky</a>
<a href="/website/index.php">Clicky</a>
<a href="..index.php">Clicky</a>
<a href="http://localhost/website/index.php">Clicky</a>
```

All seem to bring me back to the third page with whatever I've requested to be brought to appended after a # at the end of the URL. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify `rel="external"` when linking to external pages in jQuery Mobile:

```
<a href="index.php#first" rel="external">Clicky</a>
```

That link assumes that `index.php` is in the **SAME** directory as `process.php`. If it isn't, you'll have to modify the path slightly to work.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response. Yes, I tried that and it brings me to the following URL: localhost/website/process.php#index.php#first

Comment: Try <a href="index.php#first" rel="external">Clicky</a>

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Had to change some of the other internal links to complete directory links but all linking together now. Great stuff.